# Find duplicate values in list, add them and move the result to another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, iterator

I have a list that I'm trying to find duplicate values, add them to a temp list, then find the sum of the duplicate values, and then add that result to another list. The result I get is [15,6] for the following but I was expecting to get [20,12,16]? I cant seem to include all the duplicate numbers and to get the for loop to include the last number of the duplicated value. Please take a look at the following code so far, any comments would help?

```
start_list = [5,5,5,5,6,6,8,8]
temp_list = []
final_list = []

for i in range(len(start_list )-1):
    if start_list [i] == start_list [i+1]:
        temp_list.append(start_list [i])
    else:
        total = sum(temp_list)
        final_list .append(total)
        temp_list = []

print(final_list)
```

Comment: what are considered similar numbers?

Comment: Note that 1/ `range(n)` iterates from 0 to (n-1) 2/ in your `if` block, you always miss one of the identical values (try to run in with pen and paper and see...)

Comment: if you don't care about the order of the list can you do `l = [5,5,5,5,6,6,8,8]`, then `[l.count(i)*i for i in set(l)]`

Comment: similar items from the list I provided [5,5,5,5,6,6,8,8] are 5,6,8

Comment: @Musclemania05 How would you handle `[5,5,5,5,6,6,8,8,5,5]`? `[20, 12, 16, 10]` or `[30, 12, 16]`

Comment: its seems that using the counter approach from collections would handle this and produce [30,12,16] which i would expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a counter:

```
from collections import Counter

start_list = [5,5,5,5,6,6,8,8]

c = Counter(start_list)
print([x*n for x, n in c.items()])
```

Comment: yes this seems to work if unordered as well [5,5,5,5,6,6,8,8,5,5] ----- > [30,12,16]

Comment: I wondering would it also be valid if I'm using a dataset which is 200X2 with two columns of (timestamp and value) and I wanting to find timestamps that are similar by day,month,and year, and if so add those rows to a temp list and find the difference between the min/max value for that day if that makes sense?

Comment: @Musclemania05 That sounds like a separate question, particularly if you're using Pandas the answer will be different.

Comment: You could make this code shorter, by putting Counter inside of the list comprehension. `print([x*n for x, n in Counter(start_list).items()])`

Answer (score 0):

from collections import Counter

```
test=[5,5,5,5,6,6,8,8,8]
test1=Counter(test);
test2=[]

for i in test1: 
    if i==5:
        test1[i]=i*4
        test2.append(test1[i])
    elif i==6:
        test1[i]=i*2
        test2.append(test1[i])
    else:
        test1[i]=i*2
        test2.append(test1[i])
print(test1) 
print(test2)
```